# Resolution for undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass

Tags: phantomjs

We need some help in figuring out what we're missing from our tests.  We are attempting to run headless phantomjs testing and are getting the error:
          undefined method `get' for nil:NilClass
          Did you mean?  gets
                         get_key
                         gem (NoMethodError)
          features/welcome_login.feature:4:in`Given I navigate to  "http://www.web.com"'

env.rb = 
[env file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvd1O.png)